# ¿Cómo detectar el país donde estás?

Tags: php, formularios

He visto muchos formularios en los que el campo país, que por cierto no es más que un dropdown, y se me ocurrió la idea de preguntarles:

¿Cómo está hecho eso de que no es necesario seleccionar el país donde te localizas, porque ya esta seleccionado automáticamente? ¿Con qué se hace? ¿Cómo?

Comment: @luis prueba con mi solución

Comment: @Mariano Utilizo PHP

Comment: introducelo, javascript y HTML5 son lenguajes complementarios, no hay problema si los colocas

Comment: HTML5 , CSS y javascript son lenguajes desde el lado del front-end, php y otros son lenguajes del lado del backed. Esta tarea se debe realizar en el lado del fronted

Comment: @eyllanesc No es cierto que se deba realizar desde el front-end

Comment: @Mariano si se ejecuta del lado del frontend no es necesario enviarle la sesión y recargar la página para obtener estos datos

Comment: @eyllanesc Tampoco es necesario enviar sesión ni recargar desde PHP. Es lo que el autor está preguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el siguiente código puedes hacerlo, en este [post](http://www.bufa.es/jquery-detectar-pais-usuario/) nos dice:

> Un método bastante sencillo de para detectar el país (sin necesidad de
>   utilizar php para averiguar su ip) del usuario que esta entrando en
>   nuestra web es usando la API de wipmania por medio de jQuery. El
>   método de consulta nos devuelve unas cuantos parámetros como son:
>   latitud, longitud, zoom, dirección, ciudad, país, código del país,
>   región.

```js
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
    document.getElementById("pais").value = data.address.country;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="">
  Tu pais:  <input type="text" id="pais" name="">  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Pero el usuario recién editó la pregunta aclarando que está utilizando PHP. Y este mismo recurso se puede consultar desde PHP.

Comment: @Mariano Este recurso se puede utilizar al lado de PHP

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la ciudad del usuario puedes descargar:

- http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php/php-latest.tar.gz

  Una vez has descargado el archivo podras ver algunos ejemplos `examples/city.php`.

Tambien tendrá que descargar este archivo:

- http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz

y colocarlo en el mismo directorio que su archivo php.

> Un ejemplo rápido sería:

```
<?php

    include("geoipcity.inc");
    function ipAddress(){
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){ //Comprobar ip desde Internet compartido.
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){ // proxy pass ip
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
    $gi = geoip_open("GeoIPCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
    $record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi,ipAddress());
    print $record->country_code . " " . $record->country_code3 . " " . $record->country_name . "\n";
    geoip_close($gi);

?>
```

Codigo fuente:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702162/php-geo-ip-loc-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar HTML5 Geolocation y un poco de JavaScript. Yo si meto localization, le agrego un mapa, pero ya depende de tus gustos y necesidades.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            Latitud:
            <span id="latitud"></span><br/>
            Longitud:
            <span id="longitud"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {      
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    document.getElementById("latitud").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
                    document.getElementById("longitud").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
                }, function(error) {
                    alert("Código de error: " + error.code);
                    // error.code can be:
                    //   0: unknown error
                    //   1: permission denied
                    //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
                    //   3: timed out
                });
            }
        };
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hola @Mariano Ok. ya agregue un ejemplo. Muchas gracias

Comment: Y se me da el nombre del país en el que esta el usuario?

Comment: @luis no. da te las coordenadas, latitud y longitud. Podrías con esa información colocar en que país se encuentra y hasta mostrar en un mapa. Ya depende de vos.