# ¿Cómo bloquear registro por pais en PHP con https?

Tags: php

¿Hay alguna forma de saber a través de PHP la procendencia de la visita?

Me gustaría ocultar el botón de registro y mostrar un mensaje si el visitante no es de España, ya que la aplicación no funcionaría.

Algo como:

```
if($pais != "ES"){
      echo "<p>No ofrecemos servicio para tu pais.</p>";
else{
      echo "<button type='submit'>Enviar</button>";
}
```

Comment: Buenas, esta pregunta estaría respondida en esta otra, si consideras que te ha servido, ayúdala votando. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37522/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-el-pa%C3%ADs-donde-est%C3%A1s

Comment: No me sirve, necesito que sea sobre https

Comment: Puedes [probar este script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67640/29967), el cual usa GeoPlugin para determinar el país y un montón de datos posibles. Pero ojo, si se usan proxies y cosas de este tipo, nunca es 100% seguro saber de qué país se está conectando un cliente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado uno que si me sirvió:

```
$country = "";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
$country = $details->country;
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es comprobar, a través de la IP, el país del visitante.

Puedes usar la API de hostip.info.

Código de ejemplo:

```
<?php
// Cogemos la IP del usuario del array que nos pasa el servidor
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Iniciamos el handler de CURL y le pasamos la URL de la API externa
$ch = curl_init("http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=$user_ip");

// Con este comando le pedimos a CURL que, en vez de mostrar
// el resultado en pantalla, nos lo devuelva como una variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Y simplemente hacemos la petición HTTP.
$country_code = curl_exec($ch);

// Y para muestra, un botón, vamos a probar que funciona bien:
echo "Este adorable servidor ha detectado que tu código de país es... $country_code";
?>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo.

Comment: No funciona, siempre devuelve XX y además necesito que sea a través de https

Answer (score -1):

En las respuestas anteriores o no funciona la web o no es muy preciso el servicio. En mi caso me sitúa en Alcobendas, Madrid y no es el caso.

Esta otra me gusta bastante https://www.geoplugin.net

Haciendo la siguiente llamada podrás obtener la información d euna ip en formato json:
echo file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=DIRECCION_IP');

Tienes más información en este artículo: https://academy.leewayweb.com/como-restringir-el-acceso-a-una-web-segun-el-pais-del-visitante/

Acorde al comentario de [Pablo Gutierrez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/182188/pablo-guti%C3%A9rrez), **Edito y actualizo:**

```
//Obtener IP del visitante
function get_client_ip_server() 
{
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
 
    return $ipaddress;
}

$ipVisitante = get_client_ip_server();

if ($ipVisitante!='UNKNOWN')
{
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='.$ipVisitante, true ));

    $bannedCountries = array('AR', 'UY' );

    if ( in_array( $data->geoplugin_countryCode, $bannedCountries  )  ) 
    {
        echo 'No se admite gente de '.$data->geoplugin_countryName;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'Los visitantes de '.$data->geoplugin_countryName.' siempre son bienvenidos :)';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "IP desconocida";
}
```